# Delete Perl install files?

Tags: vps

I have a VPS that is managed and am mysteriously running out of space, I think I found a few files I can delete. So just double checking it's ok to delete the Perl install files:

```
/root/perl588installer.tar.gz (pretty sure this can go)
/root/perl588installer/ (wasn't sure if this can go, I'm thinking it's just used when perl is installed)
```

I rarely install this kind of thing myself but when I do I'm sure you can delete these files.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is safe to delete installer files in almost all cases. The larger issue is the disk running out of space, and the most likely culprit is log files. Take a look in `/var/log` first. Some applications log to other places, such as your home directory (`~`) or the home directory of the account they run as, and `/var/spool`.

A few commands will help you narrow it down. You can check overall disk usage with `df -h`. You can see the space consumed by all files in a directory with `du` or `ls -lS`. If you have the `find` command, you can actually search by size:

```
find / -type f -size +100M
```

will search the entire filesystem for files larger than 100 MB (careful, this may take a long time).

Comment: Thanks for the info dartonw it is very much appreciated. I'm actually about to migrate to a new vps and am running out of space trying to do a backup of my files :( I think removing the install files will give me enough space to make a successful backup.